# Why does a question I clicked the star on (to mark it as a favorite) not show in my favorites list?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bookmarks, favorites-tab

Yesterday, I clicked the star on a question to favorite it.

Today when I came back and checked my profile, it was not included on the favorites tab (sorted by newest).

It took me ages to find that question again, and when I did I can see that the star is on.

**My question**: Why does it not show in my favorites list, is it broken?

Comment: I thought "newest" referred to the question posted most recently, not when you starred it

Comment: @simchona Ahhh lol. Subject-adjective agreement failure :)  I thought newest referred to the subject at hand, ie favorites.  I'll blame bad UI design ;)  Thank you.  I found it somewhere towards the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325727/jk?tab=favorites&sort=newest) you should sort by [added](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325727/jk?tab=favorites&sort=added). This will show you recently added first.
And *newest* will show the newest question (sort by asked date).

For e.g.,

Look at [my newest favorites questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/hims056?tab=favorites&sort=newest) where you can see that the list is sorted by asked date.

Now look at [my added favorite questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/hims056?tab=favorites&sort=added) where you can see the latest added (made favorite) questions by me.